# How to convert realm list to json?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, realm

If I print my list, I've got something like this

[image]

---

But I need it to be in this format

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023249/how-can-i-convert-a-realm-object-to-json-in-swift

Comment: it returns nsdictionary, and then when I try to convert it to json it returns error, I guess it's because my realm list is of custom Question type

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate as well but... Since this is a coding forum, why don't you write the code to make that happen? You've got a List which behaves similar to an array, and each object within the list has a set of key: value pairs, like a dictionary. It's probably 20 lines of code to iterate over the array and format the objects. Oh, and it’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: Just a side note: as-is, the format presented for your data is not valid JSON. Try it with a [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)