# Swift Post Array of Realm Object

Tags: swift, realm

I have to fallowing Realm object

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class CartMeal: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = 0
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var qty = 0
  @objc dynamic var price = 0
    
}
```

And with my controller Im trying to post array of the `CartMeal` to API like below

```
class CartView: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
  
    

  var cartMeals = [CartMeal]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      fetchData()
  }


func fetchData(){
        let mealCount = RealmManager.instance.getCartMeal().count
        print(mealCount)
        if(mealCount == 0){
            
        }else{
            self.cartMeals.append(contentsOf: RealmManager.instance.getCartMeal())
        }

    }

 @objc func confirmOrder(){
       
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.1xxxxxxx/StoreResOrder")!
          var request = URLRequest(url: url)
          request.httpMethod = "POST"
          request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let param  : [String : Any] = ["meals" : cartMeals]
          request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
         let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
         configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(30)
         configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(30)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
         
          let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
              if(error != nil){
                  DispatchQueue.main.async { ....
```

But Im getting the following error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (RLM:Managed 0 CartMeal)'
```

How to solve this, any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: When posting questions, it's important to include your troubleshooting and what line is throwing the error. Best practice is to add a breakpoint and step through your code line by line inspecting the vars and code flow. When something isn't as expected, include the code, the line the error was on what what you expected it to do. As of now you have an error in JSON write (which is unrelated to Realm) but we have no idea where that error occurs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023249/how-can-i-convert-a-realm-object-to-json-in-swift You just can do ` try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: someCartMealInstance, options: [])` and it will fail I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments,  I solved the issue as below

1- make Relam object Codable

```
class CartMeal: Object , Codable{
  @objc dynamic var id = 0
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var qty = 0
  @objc dynamic var price = 0

    
     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           
           case id, name,qty,price
     }
    
}
```

2- Use JSONEncoder to covert my array to Json string

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(cartMeals)
            jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
            
        }
        catch {
        }
        let param = ["meals" : jsonString]
          request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
```