# Create a Flutter plugin in swift to export realm data

Tags: swift, flutter, realm, flutter-plugin

We have a native iOS app that has a Realm database. Now we have developed a new Flutter app that will substitute the native iOS app. When an user upgrade native iOS app to the new Flutter app, we want to migrate the existing Realm database content into the new Sqflite database.

We have created a Flutter plugin with swift **to export Realm data to json**. At the moment, we were able to add RealmSwift dependency to the plugin, but when we run the below code, it throws *Cannot find 'DeviceModel' in scope*.

Any idea to get all rows from DeviceModel table? To acomplish that is necesary to add some Realm schema manually?

```swift
import Flutter
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

enum PluginError: Error {
  case notImplemented
}

public class SwiftRealmToJsonPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "realm_to_json", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftRealmToJsonPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
      case "getPlatformVersion":
        result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)

      case "realmInfoExist":
        result(check_data())

      default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }

  // check if Realm exists
  func check_data() -> Bool {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let devices = realm.objects(DeviceModel.self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Realm object to JSON in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023249/how-can-i-convert-a-realm-object-to-json-in-swift)

Comment: Can be a part of the solution, but what we need is how can configure the Flutter plugin for access to the realm database.

Comment: Did you check out the [Realm Flutter SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/)? More importantly, you're still using Swift, right? If so then you still can access the Realm SDK. So the question is not really clear. The other thing is you cannot 'migrate' Realm to SQLLite - they are totally different databases (NoSQL vs SQL) so things like relationships and embedded objects are not directly migratable. You can export as JSON (per the above link) but it's going to be a major undertaking. Is this a one time thing? If so, use swift to read the data and dump it to a flat JSON format.

Comment: @Jay thanks for your response. I'll try to clear the doubts. The native iOS app was developed in Objective-C. We want to develop a migration plugin with swift. This native iOS app will be upgraded to a new Flutter app. The idea is export Realm data to json. This is a one time thing. I'll update my answer because we were able to add the Realm dependency to the plugin.

Comment: Realm uses Models which are the objects that act as a template to store data. Models have properties which is where the data is stored. They must appear at the top level of the App. For this `let devices = realm.objects(DeviceModel.self)` to work, a model would need to present in code called `DeviceModel`. Some good reading is located here [Object Models](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/object-models/#object-models---swift-sdk) that may add some clarity.

Comment: Oh, also note that Realm is essentially table-less; it's an object database which makes migrating to a table database like SQL a bit challenging. Here's a side-by-side quick overview which may also help [Realm vs Other Databases](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-database/#realm-vs-other-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

- Change plugin language from Swift to Objective-C and copy and paste all Realm models.
- Implement in each model class a method to generate a dictionary with it data.
- Export dictionary to json.

Right now we are able to export Realm info into a json format. Next step is implement the migration logic to adapt a table-less structure to sql.

Thanks to @Jay to point me out on the good direction to get a solution.